# How to get my blog details to display: inline-Block

Tags: blogs, css

Below is a mock up of how I would like my blog postings to look. For some reason I can not get the details them to line up horizontally. Would also like to move the gray border to below as is demonstrated in the image below. Thanks so much for the help

Here is the link to my website:
http://jobspark.ca/job-listings/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring the details links horizontally aligned, add this code to your CSS...

```
.categories, .tags { display: inline-block; }
```

And, in order to move the black line below these links, on line 8241 of your site.css file, make border-top to border-bottom